# SQL Server cursors vs multiple round trips from the application to the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, cursor

I am trying to determine if multiple round trips to the database from an application would be faster than implementing a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor on a local temp table in a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure. I will be passing in a few hundred records at a time, so that would be a few hundred round trips or a cursor through a few hundred records.

I know there are a lot of variables to take into account that would make this really hard to answer 100% accurately, but I am just wondering (as a very rough estimate) if cursors are such a performance hit that it would be worth exploring passing the data in one by one and do the logic in the application.

(Note: I know the best approach is to do set-based queries, but in this example I can not)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not test it yourself with the exact parameters and find out 100% for certain. What I can tell you with certainty is that neither approach is the best. A set based approach to what this is doing would blow the doors off either of the two methodologies you are proposing. You say that you cannot, why?

Comment: The database is not designed well, but I can't get into that nor do I have time to redesign it.  One data item updates multiple tables and some tables are given an identifier that will be used when updating a different table.  So this needs to be done sequentially which I can do with just one item at a time.  I was just trying to get an idea of where to spend my time.  If cursors were so terrible that it would be worth multiple back and forths than I would check that out.  Just thought I would ask the community of those that have more experience than I do to save me some time.

Comment: As you said we can't answer that because of the amount of variables. I understand your pain about poor database design but perhaps somebody with more experience can help you find a set based solution....hint hint. The OUTPUT clause is a great tool to utilize in situations like you are describing. If you are just doing DML then there is absolutely a set based approach that will work.

Comment: Cursors aren't as bad a performance hit as people often make them out to be.   To answer your core question, "would it be worth exploring", the answer is, "probably."

Comment: Absolutely agree with @TabAlleman here. Especially a fast forward read only isn't all that awful. It would very likely out perform a new query for every single row. But I still would put my money that a set based solution can be done here.

Comment: You've been dancing around this issue for 2 months. Your POC should have demonstrated which approach is most appropriate to your application and goals. You can try reviewing the information Erland has written [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/index.html) - but this might be beyond your abilities. So perhaps the best approach is the one that you can most easily accomplish and that is sufficiently robust and efficient. You can't know the latter two without trying. Perhaps SSIS is better suited to this task?